# How to get the return value from a function that passed from another class in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 pages, page Screen1 & page Screen2

```
class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new Screen1State();
}

class Screen1State extends State<Screen1> {
  testFunction() async {
    var response = await http.post(...);
    return "success";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => Screen2(handler: testFunction)
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new Screen2State();

  final Function handler;

  Screen1({@required this.handler});
}

class Screen2State extends State<Screen2> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    var test = widget.handler;
    print(test);    // the result will be instance of Future<dynamic> instead of "success"
  }
}
```

When I call the passed function from Screen1 on Screen2, I need to get the "success" value (which is the return value of the function) but what I got is "Instance of Future" (the type of the function).

So I wanna ask if there's any way to get the return value of the passed function from another class?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you poping screen2  and moving to screen1 after `var test = widget.handler;` ? or Do you still want to stay in screen2?

Comment: still want to stay on Screen2, because I still need to process the return value of the function on Screen2

Comment: In this case, I would assume you need a top level bloc and update bloc which emits data back to screen1 when it's active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing the following way -

```
class Screen2State extends State<Screen2> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    widget.handler().then((result) {
      print(result); // this will print "success" once the Future is complete
    });    
  }
}
```

Using `Future.then()` you can provide some code inside the `then()` method which will execute only when the `Future` is complete. Hope this helps!

Comment: thats really help, omg, i know .then from long ago but its not even come to my mind all along for this problem, silly me, hahaha, btw thank you very much for the help

Comment: btw, there's more problem, even after using .then, i think on Screen2 its not detect the function is Future (async), so before the function is done executed, .then on the Screen2 already executed, you got what i mean ?

Comment: I'm not sure how that's happening, since `then()` is only called once the `Future` completes. I'll try to replicate your code and update my answer if required.

Comment: yeah, i already try that, its just like the "await" doesnt work, what i tried earlier is to fill the async function with some post/get request, then return the value i got from the request response, but on the Screen2 i receive null, while the request response is not null, thanks for the help btw

Comment: i got my answer, sorry for the misunderstanding, actually inside the async function there's still another async function (second one), even when i call the second function using Future.then(), its not waiting till the second function done executed, so i tried to join all the process into one async function only (which passed to Screen2), then everything works fine, your answer is already correct from begining, thank you very much